# Select last record from data table for each device in devices table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with the executing speed of my sql query to postgres database.

I have 2 tables:

```
table 1: DEVICES

ID | NAME
------------------
1  | first device
2  | second device

table 2: DATA

ID | DEVICE_ID | TIME                | DATA
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 2016-07-14 2:00:00  | data1
2  | 1         | 2016-07-14 1:00:00  | data2
3  | 2         | 2016-07-14 4:00:00  | data3
4  | 1         | 2016-07-14 3:00:00  | data4
5  | 2         | 2016-07-14 6:00:00  | data5
6  | 2         | 2016-07-14 5:00:00  | data6
```

I need get this select's result table:

```
ID | DEVICE_ID | TIME               | DATA
-------------------------------------------
4  | 1         | 2016-07-14 3:00:00 | data4
5  | 2         | 2016-07-14 6:00:00 | data5
```

i.e. for each device in devices table I need to get only one data record with the last TIME value.

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM db.data d 
    WHERE d.time = (
        SELECT MAX(d2.time) FROM db.data d2 
             WHERE d2.device_id = d.device_id);
```

This is HQL query equivalent:

```
SELECT d FROM Data d 
    WHERE d.time = (
        SELECT MAX(d2.time) FROM Data d2 
            WHERE d2.device.id = t2.device.id)
```

Yes, I use Hibernate ORM in my project - may this info will be useful for someone.

I got correct answer on my queries, BUT it's too long - about 5-10 seconds on 10k records in data table and only 2 devices in devices table. It's terrible.

First of all, I thought that problem is in Hibernate. But native sql query from psql in linux terminal execute the same time as through hibernate.

How can I optimize my query? This query is too complexity:

```
 O(device_count * data_count^2)
```

Comment: Look at the second answer to the question I marked as duplicate, it has a Postgresql specific solution (`distinct on`) that could be the best choice.

Comment: Yea, u're right. I solve this: SELECT DISTINCT ON (device_id) * from db.data order by device_id, time DESC;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Postgres, you could use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to achieve this, like so:

```
select
    sq.id,
    sq.device_id,
    sq.time,
    sq.data
from (
    select
        data.*,
        row_number() over (partition by data.device_id order by data.time desc) as rnk
    from
        data
) sq
where
    sq.rnk = 1
```

The `row_number()` window function first ranks the rows in the `data` table on the basis of the `device_id` and `time` columns, and the outer query then picks the highest-ranked rows.

Comment: Thanks. It works. In ~100500 times faster. Awesome. But there is some not-postgres solution, that I can realize by HQL in named query?

Comment: @Binakot Personally, I don't have any experience writing HQL, but from what I've read online, it doesn't seem to support window functions.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support window functions or distinct on. Postgres is very powerful. I used native query to solve that. Thanks.

Comment: @Binakot awesome. don't forget to mark the best answer as "accepted" :)